# JavaScript - Variable re-declaration within a while

Tags: javascript, while-loop, scope, constants, variable-declaration

Why are const declarations within a while loop not an issue? Isn't the same variable being redeclared in each iteration?

In the code below, the `arrValue` variable is declared within the loop. I felt this would be an issue but it runs fine without errors.

Usually, I would have declared the `let arrValue;` right before the loop and accessed it within the loop without having it redeclared.

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let sum = null;
while (arr.length > 0) {
  const arrValue = arr.pop();
  sum += arrValue;
}
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: `const` (and `let`) are **block scoped** variables

Comment: `I would have declared the const arrValue; right before the loop` - which would cause your code to fail since a) you need to assign a value when declaring a const and b) you would then try to assign a new value to a **const** - which would fail, as `const` is a **constant** value

Comment: I thought block scoped means that you cant access the variable OUTSIDE of the block.
And yes, i would have to use let declaration before the while statement.

Comment: Yes, that's what it means - it also means that it's a "new" variable for each iteration